# Flutter Hive: deleteAt is making the value null instead of deleting it

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

So let's say I have a list of books.
Deleting book at nth index using `deleteAt` is not actually deleting it and shifting (n+1)th element to it's place, rather it is making it `null`. i.e. the element at nth is now `null`.

How to perform `deleteAt` perfectly?

BTW I have used delete outside of the `ValueListenableBuilder`.

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
                    valueListenable: Hive.box('books').listenable(),
                    builder: (context, box, _) {
                      if (box.values.length == 0)
                        return Center(
                          child: Text("No books"),
                        );
                      return ListView.builder(
                        primary: true,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 95),
                        itemCount: box.values.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                          Book book = box.get(index);
                          return Padding(
                            padding:
                                const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: kMasterPadding),
                            child: BookItem(
                              title: book.title,
                              author: book.authorName,
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
```

deleting code

```
() async {
      await Hive.box("books").deleteAt(Hive.box("books").length - 2);
//deleted at last 2nd coz deleting at the end was working perfectly
           },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Book book = box.getAt(index);` instead of `Book book = box.get(index);`
https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/376

Comment: Well I got the answer, that github question is also mine.

Comment: I know, just added it here as well :).

Answer (score -1):

You can [remove an element](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/List/removeAt.html) from a `List<E>` by running `.removeAt(index)` on your list. This also shifts your last elements one index to the left.

Comment: I don't have a list here, should I make one using the box?

Comment: Also is the way I am using deleteAt in my example incorrect?

Comment: Try running ```.compact()``` after you delete elements. (see the [source code](https://github.com/hivedb/hive/blob/eb300fc1394df1184ddc8b739403b6416a1b57b9/hive/lib/src/box/box_base_impl.dart) on line 141.)